# $[0,1]$ is not compact in two dimensional plane

Tags: general-topology

I have to show that $[0,1]$ is not compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I know that it is compact in $\mathbb{R}$. 
Should I have to use that every closed subset of a compact set is compact, or something else?

Comment: It is compact..

Comment: Technically, $[0,1]$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^2$. $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb R^2$ (with standard topology), though.

Comment: What topology do you put on $\Bbb R^2$ ?

Comment: thanks you@G.Sassatelli i get it

Comment: Compactness of a space $X$ is a topological property: It depends only on the  topology of $X.$  Topological properties are preserved by homeomorphic mappings. So if $X$ is compact and $X$ is homeomorphic to $X',$ where $X'$ is a subspace of a space $Y,$ then $X'$ is compact. In particular  if $X=X'\subset Y,$  then $ id_X:X\to X'$ is a homeomorphic mapping.

Answer (score 2):

A set is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded. By $[0,1]$, I take it that you mean $[0,1]\times\{0\}$. This set is both closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and is hence compact.

Comment: thanks@sahiba arora